# Mongodb aggregate pipeline for matching a reference model's field name of a sub document in a collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoose-populate

I have two collections one is Product and another is Stores

```
prouduct1 = {
name: "chair",
code: 034,
};

product2 = {
name: "table",
code: 035,
};
```

During material entry,  Stores model is updated with following schema

```
goodsReceipt = {

invoicenumber: 2,
products: [
    { product: "ObjectId(product1)", qty: 15 },
    { product: "ObjectId(product2)", qty: 20 },    
 ],
```

};

Now, i would like to go through entire store's register and matching product 1 id and then find out sum of all its qty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

db.stores.aggregate([
  { $match: { "products.product": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(productId) }},
  { $unwind: "$products" },
  { $match: { "products.product": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(productId) }},
  { $group: {
    _id: null,
    qty: { $sum: "$products.qty" }
  }}
])
```